# Count periods and duration of sick within a rolling 12 Month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and find this site to be a brilliant resource. I'm hoping for a little bit of help with a task I've been assigned.

Basically I need to find the number of periods of sickness a member of staff has taken in the last 12 month and the duration of each period of sickness.

I have a simple table that looks like this:

```
Agent Date       Status
A     01/07/2015 SHIFT
A     02/07/2015 SHIFT
A     03/07/2015 SICK
A     04/07/2015 SHIFT
A     05/07/2015 SHIFT
A     06/07/2015 SHIFT
B     01/07/2015 SICK
B     02/07/2015 SICK
B     03/07/2015 SHIFT
B     04/07/2015 SHIFT
B     05/07/2015 SICK
B     06/07/2015 SICK
C     01/07/2015 SHIFT
C     02/07/2015 SHIFT
C     03/07/2015 SICK
C     04/07/2015 SICK
C     05/07/2015 SICK
C     06/07/2015 SHIFT
```

I'm hoping someone can help me find some code that would produce the following kind of output:

```
Agent   Days
A       1
B       2
B       2
C       3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For sql-server:

```
select count(1) from TableA
  where Status = 'SICK' and Date >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -12, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)
  group by Agent
```

Grouped by periods of sickness:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', [Date]) as [number],
        RN = DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', [Date]) - ROW_NUMBER()
     OVER(PARTITION BY Agent ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', [Date]))
    FROM TableA 
     WHERE  
        [Status] = 'SICK' and 
        [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -12, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)
)
,CteFinal AS(
    SELECT
        Agent,
    startNumber = MIN(number),
    endNumber = MAX(number)
FROM Cte
GROUP BY Agent, RN
)

select Agent, endNumber - startNumber +1 as [Days] from CteFinal
group by agent, startNumber, endNumber
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79167/1)

In addition, for case with days off in table TableB:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT distinct *,
        DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', [Date]) as [number],
        RN = DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', [Date]) - ROW_NUMBER()
     OVER(PARTITION BY Agent ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', [Date]))
    FROM (select distinct * from TableA 
        union all 
        select distinct Agent, b.Date, 'DAY OFF' from TableA cross join TableB b) TableA 
     WHERE  
        [Status] IN ('SICK', 'DAY OFF') and 
        [Date] >= CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -12, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)
)
,CteFinal AS(
    SELECT
        Agent,
    startNumber = MIN(number),
    endNumber = MAX(number),
    dayOffs = SUM(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'DAY OFF' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Cte
GROUP BY Agent, RN
)

select Agent, endNumber - startNumber +1 - sum(dayOffs) as [Days] from CteFinal
group by agent, startNumber, endNumber
having(endNumber - startNumber +1 - sum(dayOffs) > 0)
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf9e4/1)

Comment: Thanks Stepan, that gives me the total day's sick an agent has taken but not the separate periods. The expected output should have agent B listed twice and show both periods as being 2 days long.

Comment: Got it. Another version added to meet all of your requirements for ms sql server. Please try it

Comment: Getting there :-) but not quite. The output now lists agent B 4 times as 4 separate periods of sick. As there is a shift between the 2 actual periods of sick I'm looking for something that recognises this and counts them separately.  So Agent B would be listed twice, each with 2 days sickness.

Comment: Second query which I've suggested with CTE returns exactly what you required - Separate record for each periods of sickness for agent and count of days of sickness for each of period. You could check it to insure this in a sqlfiddle here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79167/1
As you can see the results are equal to your expected output.
Please describe more specific, what exactly doesn't suit you in results of second query.

Comment: Apologies Stepan, it does exactly what I'm looking for. The odd thing is that when I created and populated a #Temp Table with the dummy data I used multiple:                                                                                   insert into #Temp(Agent,Date,status)
values ('A','06/05/15','Shift') and it spews out different results. Many Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help you. BTW, if it is possible to have doubles in your data, it is easy to fix to return correct results even for this case. Just change ` FROM TableA ` to `FROM (select distinct * from TableA ) TableA` in query and it will return correct data even for doubled or tripple data.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but can you help with one last thing... I've got the code looking at real data and spotted something I should have considered with the original test data. I failed to cater for rest days/holidays etc. My table will have dates missing where there are no shifts or sick. Is it possible tweak the code to cater for that? I'm thinking that the comparison be made on a row number that is partitioned on change of agent. Is that feasible?

Comment: I think I've got it, I just replaced a bit of your code to read:                  With Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        Row as [number],
        RN = Row - ROW_NUMBER()
     OVER(PARTITION BY Agent ORDER BY DATEDIFF(dd, '12/30/1899', [Date]))                                                                                                                                                                                                          after adding a row number to the table partitioned on change of agent.

Comment: I see. It is feasible. I've modified query to accounting days off stored in TableB. Please try it